# Problem in uploading image in IE8

Tags: php, file-upload

I am uploading image in php. It works fine on firefox. But on IE8 in validation it show image type is  ' image/pjpeg'. So it can not upload image due to validation of jpeg file. My code is

```
$imagetype=$_FILES['imageThumb']['type'];

    if ($imagetype!="image/gif" && $imagetype!="image/jpg" &&  $imagetype!="image/jpeg" && $imagetype!="image/png" ){
    $msg.="&bull; supported format for Thumbnail Image is gif,jpg,jpeg and png.<br>";
    }
```

any help will be appriciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why not modify your validation code to accept pjpeg? Like so:

```
$imagetype=$_FILES['imageThumb']['type'];
if ($imagetype!="image/gif" && $imagetype!="image/pjpeg" && $imagetype!="image/jpg" &&  $imagetype!="image/jpeg" && $imagetype!="image/png" ){
    $msg.="&bull; supported format for Thumbnail Image is gif,jpg,jpeg and png.<br>";
}
```

Comment: but pjpeg is not any image type

Comment: It means "progressive jpeg". It's not helpful of IE, but you can still work with the image as a normal jpeg.

Comment: Even though this would be the easiest solution, it's wrong to rely on "what the client claimed" for server-side validation. (nor file extensions, for that matter)

Comment: True, but we don't know anything about rajanikant's validation following this, and it's rather presumptuous to assume that this is all he's doing. All we know is that his posted code validates the file type reported by the browser, and that he wants to handle a different type. He didn't ask how to check an image was uploaded - he asked how to modify one line of code which has a problem with a file type sent by IE.

Comment: Definitely, just trying to pass on some knowledge. Checking the image by content (eg. image manipulation function) would, however, make the if-condition in OP redundant. If some browser decides to call jpgs image/big*ssjpgwithpixelsandstuff tomorrow, the code wouldn't break. (Besides, if rajanikant really can't figure out to add another condition to his if-statement... find another job ;))

Answer (score 1):

Don't do type detection based on what the browser sends in the first place.

Use [`getimagesize()`](http://www.php.net/getimagesize) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers behave differently with file uploads. For instance, I implemented an AJAX-y (iframe) fileupload and chrome didn't even send a mime type.

Besides that, mime-types are also not secure. A better way to check (in my opinion) is to "find out" the MIME-type server side. That way, you do not rely on the client being honest about what it's uploading.

Since the upload already happened when you are checking a mime-type, it shouldn't really add a lot of overhead either.

For PHP, there's a function called [finfo_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) which returns the MIME-type.

**edit:**
After checking the comments @ PHP Manual, it seems that the `finfo_file`-implementation isn't rock-solid either. My PHP-experience is pretty meager, so sorry about that.

Suggested alternative is, similar to what Pekka posted, to try and actually execute an image-related function on it. If that fails, "sorry client, not an image"!